# I want my prime or not program to return True and and print "True" but it's returning as None

Tags: python

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,int(num/2)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

x = int(input("Enter number"))
c = acc_p(x)

print(c)
```

Output:

> Enter number33
> None -> (I want this to be 'True')

Comment: `return "False"` instead of `break`.

Comment: And better `return True` and `return False` - i.e. booleans, not strings

Comment: But `33` is not a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reaches no return statement for the `break` case. You can return from there though:

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,int(num/2)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return "False"
        else:
            return "True"
    else:
        return "False"
```

This can be simplified as you are returning from every if-block:

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return "False"
    for i in range (2, int(num/2)+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return "False"
    return "True"
```

Ultimately you would probably want to return `bool` values. And with the short-circuiting pattern in your loop, you can use `any`:

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num <= 1:
        return False
    return not any(num % i == 0 for i in range (2, int(num/2)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns `None` when the `for` loop breaks, meaning the `else` statement will never be met:

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,int(num/2)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                break # If it breaks here...
        else:
            return "True" # This will never be met
    else:
        return "False" # And of course this one will never be met

x = int(input("Enter number"))
c = acc_p(x)

print(c)
```

What you'll want to do is return another value under the inner `else` statement:

```
def acc_p(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range (2,int(num/2)+1):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            return "True"
        return "False"
    else:
        return "False"

x = int(input("Enter number"))
c = acc_p(x)

print(c)
```

Test run:

```
Enter number7
True
```

Again:

```
Enter number33
False
```

*(Note that `33` is not a prime number.)*